# Broken link - http://java.sun.com/jsf/core warning

Tags: jsf, rad, jsf-1.2

I am using JSF1.2 and RAD6. I've added the JSF capability from the project properties but

**Broken link - http://java.sun.com/jsf/core warning**

is comeing and the JSP page is not running on the server. Any idea please?

Answer (score 1):

RAD is just acting stupid. Disable JSP taglib URI validation in its preferences. That your JSP page does not run is more likely caused by something else.

Comment: what could be the reason that JSP page is not running. i am just having a single jsp page in the whole project with following content <p>Hello</p>.

Comment: You need to be more detailed about "is not running". What exactly happens and what exactly happens not?

Comment: when i run jsp page then in J2EE perspective's server tab it shows server status as starting.. and it keeps on doing this and browser does not open.

Comment: RAD just went mad. Delete the server, shutdown RAD, check and kill any `java.exe` or `javaw.exe` entries in task manager, start RAD, create a new server (and do not touch its default settings unless you really understand what they represent and to!). Note that the "normal" start procedure is to rightclick the server and then choose start. Do not choose "Run on server" from the JSP code on. Use a normal webbrowser like Firefox, Chrome, etc to open localhost:8080 and so on.